# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.1.3

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, .net-6.0

I have upgraded from .NET Framework to .NET 6, and I have added the latest nuget package of `System.Data.SqlClient` v4.8.3, however I'm getting below error while calling one of the function.

I tried and searched all the old references of .dll but didn't find, I have cleaned and rebuild 100 times but I'm not able to trace from where this error is coming.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Code:

```
// getting error while calling below line
var content = GetConfiguration(dataType, instance);
    
public void GetConfiguration(Type dataType, ConfigurationInstance instance)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), connection))
        {
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        
            using (reader)
            {
                reader.Read();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    // do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the structure of your solution? Do you only have 1 project? Or have you separated business objects / models / data from your web or application layer? Also- you reference a variable called "connection" where does that come from and how is that instantiated?

Comment: @wazdev I have edited my code, connection is SqlConnection and the structure of the project is the above code is library and the requestor is the console webapi mvc application.

Comment: 1. Close the Visual Studio 2. End Task from the Task Manager for Visual Studio Services from Background Process and 3. try to opening the solution and Rebuild

Comment: .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6, where System.Data.SqlClient is replaced by Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. Did your old project reference the System.Data.SqlClient directly from disk or the SDK perhaps?

Comment: I would also delete all of the folders / files in bin and obj in any and all related projects. Then have a look at the references within the csproj file, sometimes these get out of alignment with nuget.

Comment: @wazdev I already tried everything, I posted an answer that helped me and it should help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I added the System.Data.SqlClient v4.8.3 nuget package in webapi console application even though it is not needed but that resolved.

Comment: .NET 6 does *not* used System.Data.SqlClient. That library was replaced by Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6 and won't load .NET Framework libraries. Perhaps your old project referenced System.Data.SqlClient directly from disk?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't see any errors or warnings and for your reference check and start using this => https://makolyte.com/system-data-sqlclient-is-missing-in-a-dotnet-core-project/

Comment: I've been using .NET Core for 3-4 years, both with System.Data.SqlClient and Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. The blog is wrong, on several points. Even in the way you add a reference - you can't use `using System.Data.SqlClient;` unless you already added the assembly reference.  In .NET Core the library is *always* added as a NuGet package, never as a direct assembly reference. To get into trouble you'd have to migrate a .NET Framework project and keep the SDK references, that now points to an invalid path.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Usually .NET 6 complains if you are adding a reference that is not supported, for this, I don't see any warnings either in the code window where the namespace is added or under references where the NuGet package is added, do you have any official link which clearly mentions that the System.Data.SqlClient is not supported